# How to pass dynamic values into snowflake query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a query to find potential SSN in a table using regex pattern.

> **db_name.schema_name.Table name:** db_name.schema_name.ABC
>   **Column name with Sensitive data:** senstve_col

```
select regexp_substr(senstve_col, '\\b[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{2}[ -]{4}\\b') as sensitive_data, * from db_name.schema_name.ABC)
```

I need to do this for 200 tables with 200 different column names. Also, the db_name and schema_name varies for each table.
Is there a way to pass the values dynamically and store the data into a new table in snowflake?
can someone help with the query to automate the above query for multiple tables?

Comment: what RDBMS it is ? `regexp_substr` is not present in SQL Server.

Comment: this is snowflake cloud datawarehouse

Comment: snowflake-schema tag does not apply to this question

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call the .SQL in unix

```
snowsql -o variable_substitution=True --variable NEXT_TABLE=tblname --variable NEXT_COL=colname -f /home/sagar/snowflake/create_table.sql
```

And this is how you mention the variable name in the .sql

```
create or replace view ntgrpa_hist.vw_rt_satelliteinfo_latest as 
select &NEXT_COL from public.&NEXT_TABLE;
```